# How to show content of items in dropdown to the active tab menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to show content of the dropdown list in the active menu, I have tried several functions in jquery and js but couldnt make it work.

Jquery function showing regular tab contents but not the content of the tabs in dropdown.

Javascript function disables all tabs and doesnt show content for any.

Here are my codes :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Show the dropdown when the "View All" link is clicked
  $(".dropdown").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from propagating to the parent element
    $(".dropdown-tab").toggleClass("active");
  });

  // Hide the dropdown when the user clicks outside of it
  $(document).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-tab").length) {
      $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    }
  });

  // Switch between tabs
  $(".tabs li.tab-link").click(function () {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr("data-tab");

    $(".tabs li").removeClass("current");
    $(".tab-content").removeClass("current");

    $(this).addClass("current");
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");
  });

  // Show tab content when drop-link is clicked
  $(".dropdown-tab .drop-link").click(function () {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr("data-tab");

    $(".tabs li").removeClass("current");
    $(".tab-content").removeClass("current");

    $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");
    $(".tabs li[data-tab='" + tab_id + "']").addClass("current");
  });
});
```

```css
.cat-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e44e4e;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs li {
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background-color: #e44e4e;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs li.tab-link:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab {
  display: none;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 90999;
}

.drop-link {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-link:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ul.tabs > li.dropdown {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-tab">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    <li class="tab-link"><a href="#" class="dropdown">View All</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-tab">
        <li class="drop-link current" data-tab="tab-5">Tab 5</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-6">Tab 6</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-7">Tab 7</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-8">Tab 8</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-9">Tab 9</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">sometext 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">sometext 2</div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">sometext 3</div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">sometext 4</div>
  <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">sometext 5</div>
  <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">sometext 6</div>
  <div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">sometext 7</div>
  <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">sometext 8</div>
  <div id="tab-9" class="tab-content">sometext 9</div>
</div>
```

I have tried javascript is well, like this :

```
function toggleDropdown() {
  var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-tab');
  if (dropdown.style.display === 'block') {
    dropdown.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    dropdown.style.display = 'block';
    var currentTab = document.querySelector('.tab-link.current');
    if (currentTab) {
      var currentTabId = currentTab.getAttribute('data-tab');
      var currentContent = document.getElementById(currentTabId);
      currentTab.classList.remove('current');
      currentContent.classList.remove('current');
    }
  }
  var tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
  tabContents.forEach(function(content) {
    if (content.classList.contains('current')) {
      content.classList.remove('current');
    }
  });
  var dropdownTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-link');
  dropdownTabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    tab.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var tabId = this.getAttribute('data-tab');
      var tabContent = document.getElementById(tabId);
      dropdownTabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        tab.classList.remove('current');
      });
      tabContents.forEach(function(content) {
        content.classList.remove('current');
      });
      tab.classList.add('current');
      tabContent.classList.add('current');
      dropdown.style.display = 'none';
    });
  });
}
```

And defined function in HTML :

```
<li class="tab-link"><a href="#" class="dropdown">View All</a>
```

Comment: Can you please create a sample in code-sandbox as it will be easier to find the issue and collaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem** :

When you click on the `drop-link` li this is calling other event handler as well i.e :  `$(".tabs li.tab-link")...` which result in hiding the tabs.

**Solution** :

One way to solve this is to exclude the `dropdown` li from your event handler i.e :  `$(".tabs li:not(.dropdown_menu)")..` . Also, you can remove some of the repeated code because , both the event handler does same work.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show the dropdown when the "View All" link is clicked
  $(".dropdown").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from propagating to the parent element
    $(".dropdown-tab").toggleClass("active");
  });

  // Hide the dropdown when the user clicks outside of it
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-tab").length) {
      $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    }
  });

  //excluding other selector...
  $(".tabs li:not(.dropdown_menu)").click(function() {
    show_hide_tabs(this)
  });
  $(".tabs li.drop-link").click(function() {
    show_hide_tabs(this)
  });

  function show_hide_tabs(el) {
    var tab_id = $(el).attr("data-tab");
    $(".tabs li,.tab-content").removeClass("current");
    $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");
    $(".tabs li[data-tab='" + tab_id + "']").addClass("current");
  }
});
```

```css
.cat-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e44e4e;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs li {
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background-color: #e44e4e;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs li.tab-link:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab {
  display: none;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 90999;
}

.drop-link {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-link:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ul.tabs>li.dropdown {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-tab">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    <!--added here one extra class-->
    <li class="tab-link dropdown_menu"><a href="#" class="dropdown">View All</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-tab">
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-5">Tab 5</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-6">Tab 6</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-7">Tab 7</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-8">Tab 8</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-9">Tab 9</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">sometext 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">sometext 2</div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">sometext 3</div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">sometext 4</div>
  <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">sometext 5</div>
  <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">sometext 6</div>
  <div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">sometext 7</div>
  <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">sometext 8</div>
  <div id="tab-9" class="tab-content">sometext 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A question for info! I will ask another question. Is it possible to to use each function for multiple tabs ?

Comment: Yes you can but , what exactly you need to do by looping ?

Comment: I have multiple tabs on same page and I want to use same code for all tabs, instead repeating code for each tab.

Comment: Yes you can .Let me know once you add another question will check that.

Comment: Would you help with this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75461119/19168006