# How to control multiple tabs with jquery on same page without affecting each other?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple tabs with same html structure and same css on same page and I want to control them using jquery without using extra plugins or bootstrap etc.

Some of the tabs has dropdown in them and some doesn't, so, I have to control tabs plus dropdowns, I mean if they have sub categories than they will have dropdowns (this is php part), if they have dropdowns and I click on the link in dropdown it should display the content of that link in active tab.

I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75455519/19168006) and the answer is the exactly what I wanted but its for simple tab.

All tabs has same html structure they are auto created by php. the only difference between them is this one `<div class="cat-tab">` its `<div class="tab-wrapper">` in real. php repeating same html structure for each category.

Example Life & Style and its sub categories and then goes on for each category.if 4 categories allowed to display on the page, then 4 tabs will have with same html structure.

1 tab for each allowed category.

Here is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-tab").toggleClass("active");
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-tab").length) {
      $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    }
  });

  $(".tabs li:not(.dropdown_menu)").click(function() {
    show_hide_tabs(this)
  });
  $(".tabs li.drop-link").click(function() {
    show_hide_tabs(this)
  });

  function show_hide_tabs(el) {
    var tab_id = $(el).attr("data-tab");
    $(".tabs li,.tab-content").removeClass("current");
    $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");
    $(".tabs li[data-tab='" + tab_id + "']").addClass("current");
  }
});
```

```css
.cat-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e44e4e;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs li {
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background-color: #e44e4e;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs li.tab-link:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 90999;
  display: none;
}

.tabs .drop-link {
  width:100%;
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .drop-link:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .cat-tab {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="cat-tab">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
        <!--added here one extra class-->
        <li class="tab-link dropdown_menu"><span class="dropdown">View All</span>
          <ul class="dropdown-tab">
            <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-5">Tab 5</li>
            <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-6">Tab 6</li>
            <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-7">Tab 7</li>
            <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-8">Tab 8</li>
            <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-9">Tab 9</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">sometext 1</div>
      <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">sometext 2</div>
      <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">sometext 3</div>
      <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">sometext 4</div>
      <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">sometext 5</div>
      <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">sometext 6</div>
      <div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">sometext 7</div>
      <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">sometext 8</div>
      <div id="tab-9" class="tab-content">sometext 9</div>
    </div>
```

I have tried `each();, $this, find();` functions to get the result but couldn't have chance.

Comment: Care to explain more about what you mean by 'control' the tabs ?

Comment: Hi, can you edit your html with what you have i.e : add the structure of other tabs maybe add example of that ?

Comment: Can you please show us the whole HTML code?

Comment: @Swati All has same html structure they are auto created by php. the only difference is this one <div class="cat-tab"> its <div class="tab-wrapper"> in real. php repeating same html structure with different categories. example Life & Style and its sub categories and then goes on for other categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for jquery will be same just the way of getting the elements will be changed.So, instead of directly accessing the element you can use `.closest()` and `.find()` .Also, the `id` should be unique so you need to make that changes on your php side code.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show the dropdown when the "View All" link is clicked
  $(".dropdown").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent the event from propagating to the parent element
    $(this).closest(".cat-tab").find(".dropdown-tab").toggleClass("active");
  });

  // Hide the dropdown when the user clicks outside of it
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".dropdown-tab").length) {
      $(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    }
  });

  //excluding other selector...
  $(".tabs li:not(.dropdown_menu)").click(function() {
    show_hide_tabs(this)
  });
  $(".tabs li.drop-link").click(function() {
    show_hide_tabs(this)
  });

  function show_hide_tabs(el) {
    var tab_id = $(el).attr("data-tab");
    var selector = $(el).closest(".cat-tab"); //here get closest outer div..
    selector.find(".tabs li,.tab-content").removeClass("current");
    selector.find(".dropdown-tab").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass("current");
    $(".tabs li[data-tab='" + tab_id + "']").addClass("current");
  }
});
```

```css
.cat-tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e44e4e;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tabs li {
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs li.current {
  background-color: #e44e4e;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabs li.tab-link:last-child {
  float: right;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab {
  display: none;
}

.tabs .dropdown-tab.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs .dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 90999;
}

.drop-link {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.drop-link:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  ul.tabs>li.dropdown {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cat-tab">
  Life Style
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    <!--added here one extra class-->
    <li class="tab-link dropdown_menu"><a href="#" class="dropdown">View All</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-tab">
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-5">Tab 5</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-6">Tab 6</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-7">Tab 7</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-8">Tab 8</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-9">Tab 9</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">sometext 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">sometext 2</div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">sometext 3</div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">sometext 4</div>
  <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">sometext 5</div>
  <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">sometext 6</div>
  <div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">sometext 7</div>
  <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">sometext 8</div>
  <div id="tab-9" class="tab-content">sometext 9</div>
</div>

<!-- for different tabs.. you need to make the id unique for now i have added -2 for each id you can change this in your php code -->
<div class="cat-tab">
  Something ..2
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1-2">A </li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2-2">B</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3-2">C</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4-2">D</li>
    <!--added here one extra class-->
    <li class="tab-link dropdown_menu"><a href="#" class="dropdown">View All</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-tab">
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-5-2">E</li>
        <li class="drop-link" data-tab="tab-6-2">F</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1-2" class="tab-content current">sometext A</div>
  <div id="tab-2-2" class="tab-content">sometext B</div>
  <div id="tab-3-2" class="tab-content">sometext C</div>
  <div id="tab-4-2" class="tab-content">sometext D</div>
  <div id="tab-5-2" class="tab-content">sometext E</div>
  <div id="tab-6-2" class="tab-content">sometext F</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are soo brilliant ! you saved me time and writing tons of extra codes :) Thank you so much.